# Setting up homestead Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I installed vagrant, virtualbox, and added homestead to my global composer requirements. I'm able to run homestead in the console with the expected output.

I am a little bit confused when it comes to editing the homestead YAML file.

```
folders: 
    - map: ~/sites/testproject
      to: /home/vagrant/testproject

sites: 
    - map: testproject.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/testproject/Laravel/public
```

That's what I put in my YAML file.

I have an existing project located under:

```
/Users/mdobrenko/sites/testproject
```

When trying to access the site via the associated IP or testproject.dev domain, I get this error:

```
No input file specified.
```

Any ideas? Homestead 2.0 seems to be a little difficult to set up for the novice from what I've heard - at least when compared to 1.0

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

Comment: Maybe you should change `sites.to` to `/home/vagrant/testproject/public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning, I got confuse as you do. But after do some searching I got this conclusion. Your YAML should looks something right this.

```
folders: 
    - map: ~/sites/testproject
      to: /home/vagrant/sites

sites: 
    - map: testproject.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/testproject/public
```

**Explanation**

```
/* Mapping path between the local machine and Homestead */
    folders: 
            - map: /* Where is your projects, you might has many projects inside  */
          to: /* The path of your project that will be on Homestead */

/* Setup the site and the root folder of the site */
    sites: 
        - map: /* The url of the project */
          to: /* Path to the public folder of the project */
```

Comment: Seems to give me the same error, even after re-starting the vagrant environment. Any other ideas? I'm thinking it might be something with the folders: map

Comment: You might need to restart the homestead after change the setting.